# If you are backward you will take a beating

Tags: translation

I look for Chinese translation for:

```
If you are backward you will take a beating
```

I do like the adage.

Comment: Why not use Google Translate? https://translate.google.ca/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=zh-TW&text=If%20you%20are%20backward%20you%20will%20take%20a%20beating

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am not sure whether it is the best way to translate properly.

Comment: It is not the best way, but at least proving you have done some research. If Google result seems odd to you, then you can post a question about particular parts of the translation and ask for clarification

Comment: That was my trying to ask the question. It was unable to me that just the translation was odd or not. That is why the question. I try to ask next question with better quality.

Comment: If you don't know any Chinese, just try to use this site as a free translation service, I am sorry, you can't do that according to the rule here. One more thing, the Google Translate result is an acceptable translation

Comment: I know, thanks for comment about the quality of Google Translate.

Comment: Just out of curiosity I did a Google Translate of "If you are backward you will take a beating" and got "如果你落后的话，你会跳动"

Comment: Is this 落后就会挨打？

Comment: @zyy exactly! Yes. Look at the answer below ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, "落后就要挨打" is the best answer.

This was first said by Stalin, in 1931, but it has been widely cited in PRC. Deng Xiaoping also quoted.

Comment: That is exactly was I was looking for. Big Thanks!

Comment: Nothing. Happy to help!